# NHibernate Source Code Location

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

can anyone tell me where I can get source code NHibernate 3.2.0.4000 and FluentNHibernate 1.3.0.717?  i looked on github but it only seems to have the source for 4.0.  Thank u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look on `sourceForge` for NHibernate

See [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/files/NHibernate/) for all versions
See [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/files/NHibernate/3.2.0GA/) for direct link for 3.2.0 GA

For Fluent look on [GitHub](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/releases) for the release tag 1.3

Comment: Ahhh!  I checked sourceforge as well but couldn't find; how the heck did I miss them?  Thnk you @Rippo!

Comment: @user1172173 All NHibernate versions are available at github - you need to select the proper tag/branch. The master branch is indeed what will become the 4.0 release.